# Unable to pass a string from vba to a windows dll

Tags: string, windows, vba, dll, parameters

I have 64 bit windows 10 with MS Office 64 bit. I am trying to get the VBA for PowerPoint to load and execute a function in a self-written 64 bit windows DLL.

The problem is that I can not pass a string from VBA to the Windows DLL. There are many discussions on various websites but I have not found one that works. 
I have tried two approaches with no success. If I use a C++ app which calls the DLL, I have no problem.

**Approach 1:**

The DLL:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) long jaadd(long a, long b, LPCWSTR strg)
    {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, strg, L"DLL", MB_OK);
    return a+b;
    }
}
```

In VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function jaadd Lib "D:\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\PopUpDLL\\x64\\Debug\\PopUpDLL.dll" _
             (ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
y = jaadd(1, 2, "abcdxxxxx")
```

Result:
y = 3 which is correct but the messagebox displays hieroglyphics.

**Approach 2 - not using wide strings:**

The DLL:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) long jaadd(long a, long b, LPCSTR strg)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, strg, "DLL", MB_OK);
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

The VBA is the same

Result:
y = 3 which is correct but the messagebox displays "nothing".

Any help gatefully received.

Comment: Strings in VBA are `BSTR`. Could be the null-terminator screwing things up.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: [BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/1b2d7d2c-47af-4389-a6b6-b01b7e915228)'s are zero-terminated, like any other C-style string. The pointer also points to the first character (not the length prefix). Even though `LPCWSTR` is the wrong type, it would still be safe to use as an argument, if it got passed a `BSTR`. @JonAnthony: Can you post the contents of the buffer passed through `strg` (starting 4 bytes lower than the pointer)?

Comment: Not sure this is legal in VBA, but you may have to be specific about the marshaling, i.e. `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> lParam As String`.

Comment: @IInspectable eh, I don't do C/C++, I was just trying to help narrowing the problem down a bit, by pointing out the fact that VBA doesn't know what to do with a `LPCWSTR` which, if I read it correctly, would be unicode-encoded, which is yet another thing to deal with (and explains the "hieroglyphs"). That said the `MarshalAs` attribute would be on the library's side, not VBA's. At least that's how it works with C# code exposed to COM.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: The `MarshalAs` attribute is part of the P/Invoke declaration, same as in C#. VBA doesn't need to know, what an `LPCWSTR` is either. If it passes a `BSTR`, the C++ code should be fine with it, even though it is not strictly using the correct type.

Comment: @IInspectable gah, I was reading the interactions upside down. Anyway there's no `MarshalAs` mechanism in VBA that I know of (that attribute syntax is VB.NET), so the library needs to deal with a `BSTR`, or figure out a way to turn it into a `LPCWSTR` (that's what "marshaling" is, no?). Unrelated (and not *yet* identified as a problem), but I also suspect that the VBA 32-bit `Long` values aren't as wide as the `long` (64-bit?) parameters the library code is adding up; this *will* cause overflows in the VBA code with larger return values.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Microsoft's C++ compiler also uses 32-bit wide `long`s (see [data type ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)), so there's no immediate additional problem (adding n-bit numbers and storing the result in an n-bit number will overflow in 50% of all possible cases anyway). As for the string type: If VBA does in fact pass a `BSTR`, there's no need for the library to convert anything. A `BSTR` already **is** a valid `LPCWSTR`. So either VBA does not pass `BSTR`s, or the marshaler does something I am not aware of.

Comment: @Mat'sMug:  I am wondering if there is an underlying problem.

If I have:__declspec(dllexport) long jaadd(long a, long b) and
Private Declare PtrSafe Function jaadd Lib "<DLL path>" _
                         (ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As Long) As Long and also y = jaadd(10, 20). Everything is fine and y returns 30.

However if I increase the number of parameters to three in the C++ and in the VBA and call with jaadd(10, 20, 30) and print out the values of a, b and c in the DLL, I get 10, 20 and 1513733088. y=1513733118. Does this indicate a stack problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your all your help. It is to do with the way VBA works with strings. I seem to have resolved the problem. If I have:

```
__declspec(dllexport) long jastr(long a, LPCWSTR strg)
```

then in VBA I have

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function jastr Lib "<DLL Path>" _
(ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As LongPtr) As Long
```

and I have

```
Dim strVar As String, ptrVar As LongPtr, y As Long
strVar = "hellothere"
ptrVar = StrPtr(strVar) ***create a pointer to start of string,ie at the 5th byte
y = jastr(40, ptrVar)
```

the messagebox in the DLL outputs hellothere and y is correct.
I do recommend the following link which was a great help:

http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-string-variables-and-pointers-in-depth

But I am still left with the problem of jaadd with three or more long parameters.